# ffmpeg How to add apng dynamic diagram on video and let it play circulated

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

**ffmpeg** How to add `apng` dynamic diagram on video and let it play circulated:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i test.png -  
filter_complex 'overlay=x=100:y=100:shortest=1' out.mp4
```

Do you have any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `movie` filter to load the APNG image and set `loop=0` to loop forever:

```
movie=test.png:loop=0
```

So in total:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
    'movie=test.png:loop=0[animation]; \
    [0:v][animation]overlay=x=100:y=100:shortest=1' \
out.mp4
```

I created a program that overlays an animated PNG on top of a video. It uses the same technique — check out [the README](https://github.com/slhck/bufferer) for an example.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g2Hn.png)  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it really a problem? The message tells you exactly what happens.